# C# Jquery Reference Error is Undefined

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a C# MVC4 application in which I am writing a JQuery function to grab some values, post to an ActionResult and then refresh a partial view.  All functionality is working except for setting a new var equal to the value of a variable within one of my div elements.

The pre-existing variable is called myName and is located in a div with an id of NameDiv.

Ive tried these four versions of code and each results in:  `Reference Error myName is not defined.`

```
    var origname = myName;    
    var origname = myName.value();
    var origname = myName.val();
    var origname = $('#NameDiv').valueOf(myName);
```

When running the application and inspecting element, I see that myName is populating with the correct value.

Comment: What do you mean by "the value of a variable within one of my div elements"?

Comment: `myName` - variable, html element, ...?

Comment: @Ian I mean that I have an html textbox with the name "myName" and the value entered by the user is what I am trying to pass and store in the var named "origname" shown above.

Comment: @HendPro12 I just added an answer. Does that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
var origname = $('#NameDiv').find('input[name="myName"]').first().val();
// console.log(origname);
```

This will find the element on the page with the `id` of "NameDiv". Then it gets the `input` elements on the page with the `name` of "myName". Then it gets the *first* one found. It will then get the `value` of it (by using `.val()`), and store that value in the variable `origname`.

Comment: I havent tried yet but I dont believe it will because I have two textboxes in the div

Comment: @HendPro12 Do both textboxes have the same `id` "NameDiv"?

Comment: neither textbox has an id at this moment each just has a "name."  However, both are located in a div with the id "NameDiv."  Is there no way to do what Im desiring without giving each individual textbox an id?

Comment: @HendPro12 It would definitely be more helpful if you provided more code/HTML. I just updated my answer with hopefully a better solution. Sorry I misunderstood at first